# How can I get data from my online mysql database to my pc so I can use it in my application?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cloud, replication

I want to fetch the data from a web-based database into my application.

The data is in a MySQL server with phpMyAdmin. If I want the data local I can't use ODBC because that's not supported and master-master replication is also very difficult because one database is in the cloud and the other is just in the local network.

How can I get the data from my online database to my PC so I can use it in my application?

Comment: You can create a user with password and rights to connect from anywhere in the remote db. Then you can use PDO or MySQLi to connect to the remote database. If you just want to have your data locally, export the entire DB as SQL using phpmyadmin, if possible (size restrictions), then create a db and import the SQL there.

Comment: I want them to be the same like a master-master replication. If I change one thing in one of the databases it must be changed real-time in the other.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402794/mysql-replication